# Java class/objects output double with (,) and change decimal places

Tags: java, class, object, decimal

How do I input doubles such as 4,10, in the main class?

If not, how do I print the result as 4,10, after inputting 4.10?

Also, the trailing zero after the decimal is lost, after printing the result, how do I fix that?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Pizza Rentals = new Pizza("Rentals",4.10);
    Pizza Strength = new Pizza("Strength ", 3.10);
    Pizza Molissimo = new Pizza("Molissimo", 4.20);

    System.out.println(Rentals.getName() + " (" + Rentals.getPrice() + " euros)" );
    System.out.println(Strength.getName() + " (" + Strength.getPrice() + " euros)" );
    System.out.println(Molissimo.getName() + " (" + Molissimo.getPrice() + " euros)" );

}
```

**Class**

```
class Pizza{

  String name;

  double price ;


  Pizza(String name, double price){

      this.name = name;
      this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName(){
      return name;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
      return price;
  }

  public String toString() {

      return super.toString() ;
  }
}
```

Desire outcome;

Rentals (4,10 euros)
Strength  (3,10 euros)
Molissimo (4,20 euros)

Comment: add a formatter. but if that's the way you want to print the info of a pizza, just put all that in the toString method. the toString method you have now makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your given input one of the solutions can be to implement `DecimalFormat` as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    sym.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);

    Pizza Rentals = new Pizza("Rentals", 4.10);
    Pizza Strength = new Pizza("Strength ", 3.10);
    Pizza Molissimo = new Pizza("Molissimo", 4.20);

    System.out.println(Rentals.getName() + " (" + df.format(Rentals.getPrice()) + " euros)");
    System.out.println(Strength.getName() + " (" + df.format(Strength.getPrice()) + " euros)");
    System.out.println(Molissimo.getName() + " (" + df.format(Molissimo.getPrice()) + " euros)");
}
```

Comment: A better way would to put all that formatting in the toString method, and simply call it like: System.out.println(Rentals); // though following naming conventions would make the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

use `java.text.MessageFormat` with correct `java.util.Locale`

Example as JUnit-Test:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jk
 */
public class MessageFormatTest {

     @Test
     public void hello() {
         MessageFormat fmt_EN = new MessageFormat("{0,number,#0.00}", Locale.ENGLISH);
         assertEquals("4.10", fmt_EN.format(new Object[] {4.10}));
         MessageFormat fmt_DE = new MessageFormat("{0,number,#0.00}", Locale.GERMAN);
         assertEquals("4,10", fmt_DE.format(new Object[] {4.10}));
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I appreciate it, the first response worked well, I look forward to where I can use your method